# which IP address will show

Tags: ip-address

If i compose a draft email on my laptop at home in one country and then travel to another and send the email will the IP address be the one where the email was composed or the one where it was sent from?

Comment: What do you mean by "the IP address"? The IP address of what?

Comment: Neither IP Addresses will be shown.  The only IP Address shown will be the server that actually sent the email.

Comment: @Ramhound, actually no IP is shown by default to the user who reads the mail. If he looks in the complete mail headers, he will find the IP of the mail server first of course but usually he will find the IP from which the mail server received the mail too (and the whole path of the relays). As a small example of what can be done with mail headers, there are addons for Thunderbird (and probably other clients) that display all the headers and even the mail client that was used to write the email...

Answer (score 3):

The one it was sent from but this will be the IP of the mail server, not your local IP. Your local IP can be found looking at the details of the header of the mail but it will always be the IP you had when you sent the email not while writing it.

Comment: Is this true? Or will the IP be the server from which it sends, depending on what email protocol is used (IMAP, POP, Exchange etc)?

Comment: Sure the ip of the server will be the main IP but if you look inside the details of the header, you can find the IP from where the server received the email before sending it.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know that, thank you.